# Is there a Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality for martingale increments?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

is there a Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality for martingale increments?
More specifically, I would like to find a finite bound of order $h^{p/2}$ for the expectation
$$\operatorname{E} \left[ \sup_{t \geq 0} \left| \int_t^{t+h} X_s \, \mathrm{d} B_s \right|^p \right]$$
where $B$ is a Brownian motion and $\operatorname{E} \left[ \sup_{s \geq 0} |X_s|^p \right]< \infty$. If the increment would be fixed, one could apply Burkholder-Davis-Gundy, but unfortunately this is not the case. 
Is there some kind of standard method to handle this case or even a Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality for increments?

Comment: No, even in the simplest case that $X\equiv 1$ one should note that $\sup_{t \geq 0} |B_{t+h}-B_t| = +\infty$ a.s., since $(B_{(n+1)h}-B_{nh})_{n\ge 0}$ is an iid sequence of Gaussians. One might hope that this is true in case you have an extremely strong decay condition on $X$.